# Area of triangle formed by three complex numbers $-z,iz$ and $z-iz$ in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The question bothering me is "Find the area of a triangle formed by the complex numbers $-z,iz,z-iz$ in the argand plane.

I'm really sorry, but I could not understand how to proceed. However to that extent I thought I start by assuming $z=a +ib$. Then $-z = -a-ib$ and $iz= -b+ia$. How do I proceed further?

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for displaying numbers and functions.

Comment: Suggestion: Make a sketch of the triangle for the case $z = 1$, and calculate its area. Then use geometry to figure out how area changes when all three vertices are multiplied by $z = r e^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggest, let $$z=a+ib\Rightarrow iz=-b+ia, z-iz=a+b+i(b-a)$$

Then the area of the triangle formed by the vertices $(-a,-b),(-b,a),(a+b,b-a)$ is $$\frac 12\left|\begin{matrix}-a&-b&a+b&-a\\-b&a&b-a&-b\end{matrix}\right|$$
$$=\frac 12\left|-a^2-b^2-b^2+ab-a^2-ab-ab-b^2+ab-a^2\right|$$
$$=\frac 32(a^2+b^2)$$

Comment: $$\ldots = \frac 32 |z|^2$$

Comment: yes, of course! thanks

Comment: thank you errally appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

For any complex number $z$, when you multiply it by $i$ you are rotating that vector by $90^{\circ}$ in the counterclockwise direction. So now try to visualize what kind of a triangle you will get in your question.

Answer (score 2):

When $z=1$ you have the triangle $T$ with vertices $-1$, $i$, and $1-i$. Its area is ${3\over2}$. Multiplying these three vertices with the complex number $z$ is a similarity map, centered at $O$: The triangle  $T$ is stretched linearly by the factor $|z|$ and rotated  by ${\rm arg}(z)$. It follows that in the end you have a triangle of area ${3\over2}|z|^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You can notice that all vertices are defined as $z$ multiplied by some constant:
$$
\begin{align}
-z & = z \cdot (-1)\\
iz & = z \cdot i\\
z-iz &= z \cdot (1-i)
\end{align}
$$
So you can analyze the triangle with vertices $-1, i, (1-i)$ (complex), that is $(-1,0), (0,1), (1,-1)$ (cartesian) first. You will find it is isosceles with a base of $\sqrt 2$ and a height $\frac 32 \sqrt 2$, so its area is $\frac 32$.

When you multiply all vertices by arbitrary $z$, they all get scaled with respect to $(0,0)$ by factor $|z|$ and rotated by angle $\arg z$. Rotation does not affect the area of a figure, but scaling applies to the area with a square, hence the answer $$\frac 32 \cdot |z|^2$$